# Coalesce not evaluating second argument?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions

I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(count(percent_cov), 0)
FROM sample_cov
WHERE target = 542
GROUP BY percent_cov
HAVING percent_cov < 10
```

Basically, I want to show the number of times this statistic was < 10, and return 0 rather than null if the count was 0. If the count is >0 I get the number I want as the result, however if the count is 0 I still get a null returned. (Same thing if I set the second argument to coalesce as a positive number). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I rewrote your query the way I *think* you want it:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   sample_cov
WHERE  target = 542
AND    percent_cov < 10;
```

`count()` returns `0` When no matching rows (or non-null values in the column) are found. No need for `coalesce()`. I quote [the manual on this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

> It should be noted that **except for count**, these functions return a
> null value when no rows are selected.

Bold emphasis mine. If you want to return a different value when `count()` comes back with `0`, use a `CASE` statement.

Also, it's no use to write `count(percent_cov)` while you have `WHERE percent_cov < 10`. Only non-null values qualify, `count(*)` yields the same result slightly faster and simpler in this case.

You don't need a `GROUP BY` clause as you don't group by anything, you are aggregating over the whole table.
You *could* `GROUP BY target`, but this would be *a different query*:

```
SELECT target, count(*)
FROM   sample_cov
WHERE  percent_cov < 10
GROUP  BY target;
```

You would need to spell out the expression in the `HAVING` clause again. Output column names are visible in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, not in `WHERE` or `HAVING`.

Comment: This does work, thank you! I guess I was making things harder than they needed to be.

Comment: @user1453804: Yeah, I guess. :) But most things in programming seem easy once you know how.